# Ways to win a cricket match with 100% probability

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

In a recent contest this was one of the problems asked:

**Problem Statement:**

Pranay and Sumith are playing a cricket match. Sumith's team has scored X runs. Pranay's team has scored Y runs. There are 6 balls remaining in the match, and they have lost 9 wickets. Mahesh is currently on strike, and Pranay is at the non-striker's end. Pranay is not good at batting and will lose his wicket if he gets to bat. However, Mahesh is a proficient batsman and is not expected to lose his wicket.

NOTE: The bowler doesn't bowl any extra balls like wides or no-balls. Each ball is a regular delivery. And maximum of 3 runs can be scored by running between the wickets per ball.

Mahesh's girlfriend is fond of permutations and is watching the match. She is curious to know the number of ways Pranay's team can win the match with a 100% probability, given the remaining balls, wickets, and the current score. Your task is to help her determine the number of ways Pranay's team can win the match with a 100% probability.

**Input Format:**

Each test consists of multiple test cases. The first line contains a single integer t — the number of test cases.
The description of test cases follows:

The first and only line of each test case contains two integer values X and Y — where X represents the score of sumith's team and Y represents score of pranay's team

**Constraints:**

1 <= t <= 10^7

1 <= Y < X <= 500

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> runs = {0, 2, 4, 6};
int helper(vector<vector<int>> &dp, int &target, int curr, int ball){
    if (curr >= target) return 1;
    if (ball > 6) return 0; 
    if (dp[ball][curr] != -1) return dp[ball][curr];
    int ans = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) ans += helper(dp, target, curr + runs[j], ball + 1);
    return dp[ball][curr] = ans;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        int target = x - y + 1; // You need 1 more than the required difference of X and Y
        vector<vector<int>> dp(7, vector<int>(target + 1, -1));
        cout << helper(dp, target, 0, 1) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**My Logic:**

I have used a top down memoised recursive approach to solve this problem. At each ball (i.e each recursion call), possible runs out of the runs array gets added to the current score (curr). The base case is that if the current score becomes larger than the target, then return 1 else if ball is greater than 6 return 0 (as total balls left are only 6). The possible runs are {0,2,4,6}. 1 and 3 are not possible because in both those cases Pranay would reach the striking end and that would not give us a 100% probability of victory. 5 is not possible as each ball is a regular delivery and maximum runs that could be ran and obtained is 3.

**Some Test Cases:**

Input:

```
4
37 2
38 5
12 10
12 11
```

Output:

```
1
7
57
18
```

These are some of the testcases that I ran. They run correctly.

The problem is that my code runs on few of the starting test case but gives wrong answer on all the subsequent ones. I have no access to those hidden test cases. Please help me find the loophole in my code.

[Rules of Cricket](https://www.rulesofsport.com/sports/cricket.html)

Comment: what test cases did you run yourself? What did you find when you used a debugger and checked your assumptions about what the code does?

Comment: I would start with removing `using namespace std;`, then adding `void solution(std::istream& input, std::ostream& output);` and then writing a bunch of unit tests for different situations. If this programming puzzle site doesn't give you enough visible tests, compute some scenarios in your head and add then to your fixture.

Comment: [Here you go](https://godbolt.org/z/oYaGGPrjP) - first thing to notice is that for most of the big score differences you can probably return immediately.

Comment: `DSA Problem` -- Off topic, but many persons reading your question have no idea what `DSA` is supposed to mean.  On StackOverflow, the `dsa` tag means `Digital Signature Algorithm`.  As to this, I have been in the industry many years, and I have never heard "data structures" and "algorithms" abbreviated as "DSA".

Answer (score -2):

**There is a flaw in your code**. As the target can be reached after 6 balls, but that may not happen. If the target is not reached within 6 balls then the number of ways to win the match is 0, regardless of the current score.

To fix this flaw, you can add a check at the start of the recursive function to see if the target can be reached in the remaining balls. Otherwise return 0.  Here is an updated version of your code with the error fixed:

Here I have fixed the code:

```C++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> runs = {0, 2, 4, 6};
int helper(vector<vector<int>> &dp, int &target, int curr, int ball){
    if (target > runs[ball] * (6 - ball) + curr) return 0; // Return 0 if target is not achievable in remaining balls
    if (curr >= target) return 1;
    if (ball > 6) return 0; 
    if (dp[ball][curr] != -1) return dp[ball][curr];
    int ans = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) ans += helper(dp, target, curr + runs[j], ball + 1);
    return dp[ball][curr] = ans;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        int target = x - y + 1; // You need 1 more than the required difference of X and Y
        vector<vector<int>> dp(7, vector<int>(target + 1, -1));
        cout << helper(dp, target, 0, 1) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, now you introduced the UB by accessing the vector out of bounds.

Comment: The runs array here is being used to store possible runs which can be added to the current sum. The ball variable is to keep a track of the number of the bowl which is being bowled (i.e the number of recursion call). ball variable is not an index of the runs array.